# Error in importing openface

Tags: python

I installed openface using the [link](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-dlib-on-ubuntu/)

But when i am importing openface in python it is giving an error

```
./util/align-dlib.py ./home/admin1/Dhoni/ align outerEyesAndNose    ./aligned-images/ --size 96
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./util/align-dlib.py", line 24, in <module>
import openface
ImportError: No module named openface
```

Please help me!!!!!

Comment: try to 'import openface'' in python console. This show you that openface is installed or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux,

1. Clone the project :https://github.com/cmusatyalab/openface
2. cd openface
3. python setup.py install
4. Then create an empty file named `__init__.py` inside the openface/ directory
5. Try running the demo command : ./demos/compare.py images/examples/{lennon*,clapton*}

**Note**: If the demo fails due to dependency issue, try to install those dependencies. Like in my case I had to install following as well

```
luarocks install torch
luarocks install nn
luarocks install dpnn
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your terminal:

cd /home/*your_username*/openface

python setup.py install

This should help you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting the error because

> python setup.py install

was not installing it for my virtual environment, despite activating it. I had to run the following to force it to be installed in the venv:

```
<virtualenv path>/bin/python setup.py install
```

In Linux, this gives you the path to the python in your venv:

```
which python
```